# ui.bootstrap.datepicker $watch for input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using an `ui.bootstrap.datepicker` like this:

```
    <input type="text"
only-digits
id="startDate"
class="grey-input"
datepicker-popup="{{dateFormat}}"
ng-model="userSettings.auto_reply_start_date"
is-open="startDate.opened"
min-date="minDate"
datepicker-options="dateOptions"
date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"
show-weeks="false"
show-button-bar="false"
close-text="Close"/>
```

and `only-digits` is a directive in which I'm trying to filter user input.

But, I can't use `$watch`, cause this code:

```
    link    : function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (newValue, oldValue) {
```

fires only wnen the date is selected from the datepicker, but not entered inside text input.

How can I watch it?

Comment: Try to use `ng-change`.

Comment: @Joy, no, that did not helped

Comment: Then put some JSFiddle/Plunker code.

Comment: I guess I've found a solution - at leas this is something that works

Answer (score 0):

I've dived into the src and found this `$parser`
function parseDate(viewValue) {
        if (angular.isNumber(viewValue)) {
          // presumably timestamp to date object
          viewValue = new Date(viewValue);
        }

```
    if (!viewValue) {
      return null;
    } else if (angular.isDate(viewValue) && !isNaN(viewValue)) {
      return viewValue;
    } else if (angular.isString(viewValue)) {
      var date = dateParser.parse(viewValue, dateFormat, scope.date);
      if (isNaN(date)) {
        return undefined;
      } else {
        return date;
      }
    } else {
      return undefined;
    }
  }
```

So, the only way to do what I need was as follows:

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require : 'ngModel',
    priority: 1000,
    link    : function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
            //validation goes here
            return viewValue;
        });
    }
};
```

This makes validation possible and doesn't spoil datepickers's behaviour